# Why we use karate-config.js file? but we use Java technologies

Tags: karate

Why Karate configure file is karate-config.js file but we are us Maven or Gradle deployement tools.

Answer (score 0):

Explained in the docs, but you actually need to read it: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-configjs

[image]